# iframe breaking jquery.contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

So I am trying to do some inner HTML pop up window work, by using `Jquery.contents()` on a hidden div to place the content in the pop window on click.

For some reason, if any of the divs have an `iframe` in them, all the divs after them in the html will not be able to be appended. Is this some sort of bug? Here is an example:

```
<div class="hide">
    <div id="apps">
        <iframe src="http://ryansaxe.info/javascriptpaint" />
    </div>
    <div id="contact">
        <ol>
            <li>Phone: (111)-111-111</li>
            <li>Email: email@gmail.com</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <div id="resume">
        <p>resume</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the case above, only the `#apps` content reads, because it has an iframe, and all contents after that then don't read. If the `div` with the `#apps` id was last, every single one would have readable contents through Jquery.contents()

## [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zgdHK/)

## note:

Here is my jquery

```
$('.open').click(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    var selector = $(name);
    var cont = selector.contents();
    $('#pop').append(cont.clone());
});
$('.close').click(function(){
    $('#pop').empty();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like scripts, you cannot use the `/>` syntax with `iframe`s. Explicitly write out the `</iframe>`:

```
<iframe src="http://ryansaxe.info/javascriptpaint"></iframe>
```